# APNS registration and its life cycle

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

I am planning to use Apple APNS service in my app. I went through documentation and found that I need to call `registerForRemoteNotifications()` from app so that app will send device token through appdelegate method.

As per my understanding apple changes device token in certain scenario's like OS update, restore backup etc.

I have little confusion here - is that ok if we call `registerForRemoteNotifications()` only once? or do i need to call it after each app launch?

If I call it once and never call `unregisterForRemoteNotifications()` from app, will app always receive push even though apple update device token?

Comment: Apple documentation: for security and privacy reasons, it must change when the device is wiped, Thats mean you have to update your token on server again

Comment: yes agree but lets say i never call registerForRemoteNotifications will it work always? (here i am assuming user has not disable from setting)

Comment: registerForRemoteNotifications used to initiate the process of APNS , if you never call it its mean APNS not initiate and you cant use push notification

Comment: Ok Let me correct it.. If i call it once lets say for first app launch and for next all app launch if i never call registerForRemoteNotifications... will APNS work? I assume.. if i call atleast once device will be registered for APNS with apple and I dont need to call it again...

Comment: never work if you not call it next time , just follow the apple document all the time when application start they call it in didfinishlaunching function with user notification setting.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider calling `registerForRemoteNotifications` in every app launch, directly from your delegate method :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

Like this :

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
```

Like this, you'll always have the uptodate **push token**.

See [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/HandlingRemoteNotifications.html) on this subject.